# Multi purpose login/signup form MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I'm looking for an extensible implementation of a dual purpose login/signup form, written for MSofts MVC3.

It's a bit tricky, since the two have different validation requirements.

Some details in response to comments:

- Dual purpose as in, the form should be able to serve for both sign-in and sign-up purposes.
- The trickiest part is probably the validation, and I would be surprised if a solution doesn't use custom validation code to work properly
- Extensible so I can use my own fields rather than some hard coded fixed ones. I've found some solutions where extending them was the same order of magnitude of effort as starting from scratch

Comment: Could you explain? What's the problem? Did you tried anything yourself or you just want someone to give you the full code for whatever is it you want? And a "dual purpose login/signup form"? Which purposes?

Comment: I've tried everything myself, found out that it is hard, and time consuming, and, since this is a fairly common sort of problem most people are likely to see, am wondering if someone else has already solved it. I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a difficult problem.  You simply create two different forms in the view, one that posts to your Registration method, and one that posts to your Login method.  Because each form posts to a different Action method, they use different models, and thus different validation.

Example:

```
@using LoginRegisterModel
...
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account")) {
    ... Your Register form
    <input type="submit"/>
}

@using (html.BeginForm("Login", "Account")) {
    ... Your login form
    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

In your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model) {
    // do your registration
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model) {
    // do your login
}
```

In your models:

```
public LoginRegisterModel {
     public LoginModel {get; set;}
     public RegisterModel {get; set;}
}
```

It's often easier to put each form in a Partial View, then you can pass only the relevent model to the partial.

Comment: eeew. All that duplication, both in the two forms, and in the model. Dozens of duplicate lines for just a few input elements :( Is this the best I can do here? Two forms and two models, especially when one is a superset of the other, seems so ugly.

Comment: Also, how do I distinguish between the two models in the view? I seem to only be able to use one @model directive at a time. Do the standard @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName) autogeneration methods still work with two models in one view?

Comment: @blueberryfields - You asked for a simple, extensible solution.  There is nothing simpler or more extensible.  And the overlap is minor, two fields (username and password), and what you do with those values is completely different, so complaining about duplication is, IMO, silly.

Comment: @blueberryfields - You create a wrapper model that contains both.  Validation occurs in the postback, so it only validates the model that gets bound to the post method.

Comment: Sure, if I have to suck up the ugliness, I will. If you tell me this is the best that can be done, then fine. It's small, and contained, and I probably never have to look at it again. But each of the two fields is backed by upwards of 50 lines of code (!!), which are duplicated. It's small, but it's *very* ugly.

Comment: cool. This is definitely better than what I've come up with - thank you!

Comment: @blueberryfields - I don't understand your comment about the fields being backed up by 50 lines of code?  The processing you do for a login is different from the processing you do for a registration.  If there is common code, refactor it to a method that you call from both.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5419/discussion-between-blueberryfields-and-mystere-man)

Comment: @blueberryfields - By the way, most people get hung up on DRY (don't repeat yourself), but another principle that's just as important is SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) which says a method or object should do only one thing.  Making your objects complex just to save some typing makes them harder to maintain in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

So take the default code from both the signup form and the registration form found in an out of the box MVC application and place those two into a new view called 'dualPurposeLoginSignup' and use that as your login page. Once you do that you should now have what you're looking for.

Good luck with your project.

Comment: I'm confused. How would you address the validation differences between login (where you only validate the the uid and password are correct) and signup (where you validate that the uid is not in use, the password has the correct format, the email is an actual address, etc...)?